# Will Enduring Ideal and Dovescape played together leave Enduring Ideal countered?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play [Enduring Ideal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enduring%20Ideal) and search and play [Dovescape](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dovescape).

On the next upkeep Enduring Ideal should be cast again.

Is Enduring Ideal countered by Dovescape, or can I search for other enchantments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, a copy of Enduring ideal won't be countered by Dovescape because the copy isn't cast.**

The reminder text for Epic says:

> At the beginning of each of your upkeeps, copy this spell except for its epic ability.

However, copies are not cast and thus are not affected by Dovescape:

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; **a copy of a spell isn’t cast** and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. [...]

Comment: Thanks for editing and answer! I found the card link is not working (Not showing any card) What tag or code to use for linking card easily for next time?

Comment: Don't know, the links are working for me. The format is [mtg:cardname], though certain special characters like ' cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Enduring Ideal is not cast, since you cannot cast spells, a copy of it (without Epic) is just put on the stack. Since it is not being cast Dovescape doesn't care about it and it is not countered.